# Postgres regex to get substring from path

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to get a substring from a path directory made of 2 numbers preceeded and followed by a '_'. The string is like:

```
'P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFENTECONTROL\2011_9_43\2011_9_46_43_29_10.ZIP'
```

and in this case I want to get the 43 following the 46.

The path is stored following the next rule, after the last backslash:

```
'\TablesPK_twoCharactersClassification_twoCharactersDocumentType_anything.ZIP'
```

I want to get the classification. The catch is that the table's primary key could be more than one field, although I know in each case how many fields are in the pk.

I got with something like this:

```
select substring(substring(substring('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFENTECONTROL\2011_9_43\2011_9_46_43_29_10.ZIP' from '([^\\]*(\.ZIP|zip))') from '([^_]*_){4}') from '[0-9]{2}')
```

But I would like something simpler.

Other cases:

```
'P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFENTECONTROL\2011_03_46\2011_03_46_46_48_.ZIP'
```

(need the second 46)

```
'P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFCONTABLE\2009_05_INBP\2009_05_INBP_22_28_.ZIP'
```

(need the 22 after INBP)

```
'P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFOFICIAL\2007_06_MB\2007_06_MB_29_28_.ZIP'
```

(need the 29)

```
'P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\ASOCIADOS\8010625\8010625_02_04_20110111.ZIP'
```

(02 after 8010625)

In the last case, the pk is only one field, so I've changed the sentence as:

```
select substring(substring(substring('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\ASOCIADOS\8010625\8010625_02_04_20110111.ZIP' from '([^\\]*(\.ZIP|zip))') from '([^_]*_){2}') from '[0-9]{2}')
```

For one Pk, I need the second set of `([^_]*_)`, for three the fourth, and so on..

```
select substring(substring(substring('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\ACTASCOMITE\ACRE123\ACRE123_17_11_.ZIP' from '([^\\]*(\.ZIP|zip))') from '([^_]*_){2}') from '[0-9]{2}')
```

(I get 17)

I'm using postgres 9.0.

Comment: Would also be helpful to add a couple more example values with possible variations to make clear what you need. And add what your database has to say to `SHOW standard_conforming_strings;`, please.

Comment: Why is there no `_` before `.ZIP` in `8010625_02_04_20110111.ZIP`?

Comment: It's not mandatory. After the "TwoCharactersDocumentType" could be anything. The only thing sure is that after the table's primary key always goes the classification and document_type.

Comment: But it's always `_` and digits between the two digits and `.zip`? I think I got it all in my solution now.

Comment: No, after _02_04_ could go numbers or letters or more '_', it's not sure. That's why I start filtering from the last backslash, because before the .zip could go anything. it follows thi "format" \TablesPK_twoCharactersClassification_twoCharactersDocumentType_anything_including_letters.ZIP. The classificafion and document type are always between "_" lower hyphen.

Comment: ... anything except "\" I assume. That's in my regexp now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am beginning to understand. Consider this test case:

```
WITH x(txt) AS ( VALUES
     ('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFENTECONTROL\2011_9_43\2011_9_46_43_29_10.ZIP')  -- 43
    ,('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFENTECONTROL\2011_03_46\2011_03_46_46_48_.ZIP')  --need the second 46
    ,('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFCONTABLE\2009_05_INBP\2009_05_INBP_22_28_.ZIP') --need the 22 after INBP
    ,('P:\pgdfecol\71698384737978\INFOFICIAL\2007_06_MB\2007_06_MB_29_28_.ZIP')      --need the 29
    )
SELECT txt, substring(txt, '\\(?:[^_\\]+_){3}(\d\d)_[^\\]*\.(?:ZIP|zip)$')
FROM   x
```

`(?:)` .. non-capturing parenthesis
`[^_\\]`.. character class with any character except `\` and `_`
`\d` .. a digit, same as [0-9] effectively
`+` ..  1 or more matches (greedy)
`$` .. end of string
`[_\d]` .. character class with digits and `_`

The case with only one pk needs a different pattern. Use `{1}` instead of `{3}`.

Not sure why you escape the backslashes. In modern versions of PostgreSQL [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html) is `on` by default so you don't need to escape backslashes in strings - but still in regular expression of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but it shows nothing to me, an empty string as result. I've escaped the backslash because it gives me an error "non-standar use of '\\' in string literal..." in pgAdmin 1.14. Besides, the primary key could be of any number of fields, and not only digits.

Comment: @nowxue You need to disclose your version of PostgreSQL. *Always*. Add that to your *question*. I suspect you have an older version with `standard_conforming_strings =  off` ... pgAdmin is only the GUI and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: No, you're right. The escaped backslashes are not needed in the string, but in the regex